Encountered `ValueError` while training a farama gymnasium AI bot
I am working with farama gymnasium trying to make an ai to learn to play an atari game. But I am encountering this error. Here is my code:
import gymnasium as gym
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
from rl.policy import LinearAnnealedPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy

env = gym.make('Berzerk-v0', render_mode="human")
height, width, channels = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n


episodes = 3
for episode in range(1, episodes + 1):
    state= env.reset()
    
    done = False
    score = 0

    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = random.choice([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])
        
        n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        if done or truncated:
            break
    print(f'Episode: {episode} Score: {score}')
    print(n_state)
env.close()

def buildModel(height, width, channels, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, (8,8), strides=(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape=(height, width, channels)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (4,4), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation="linear"))
    
    return model


model = buildModel(height, width, channels, actions)
model.summary()
print(env.observation_space.shape)
def buildAgent(model, actions):
    policy = LinearAnnealedPolicy(EpsGreedyQPolicy(), attr='eps', value_max=1, value_min=0.1, value_test=.2, nb_steps=10000)
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=1000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, enable_dueling_network=True, dueling_type='avg', nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=1000)
    return dqn



dqn = buildAgent(model, actions)

dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), metrics=['mae'])


dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=10000, visualize=False, verbose=2)
 

Here's the error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

I was following along a youtube tutorial, and it seems like the code is outdated and I could not find a solution anywhere.

Please show the full traceback, and put it inside the main content as formatted text, rather than putting the error message in your title. Your title should be a summary of the issue, not the error message.
